# How can I insert at the start of a line a string dependent on two other string values that define beginning and end locations using python note++

Tags: python

How to use Python plugin for note++ for the example below...please advice

So for example, I have

```
First
x
y
z
Second
a
b
c
Third
d
e
f
The result I would like to achieve is;
First
Q1 x
Q1 y
Q1 z
Second
Q2 a
Q2 b
Q2 c
Third
Q3 d
Q3 e
Q3 f
```